# Pandas column has an np array of json objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that has the following shape.
[image]

as you can see, the column entities have an np array of JSON objects, and sometimes, it's empty.
I want to flatten this column into the data frame by taking the first 5 JSON objects.
Every JSON object has indexes (name, type, mid, wikipediaUrl, numMentions, avgSalience), but the number of objects in every row varies from non to 30 or 40.
here is a minimal reproducible sample.

```
import json 
dict0 = [{'name': 'require-once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.014624}, {'name': 'require_once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.008366},{'name': 'funkytaurusmedia.com/includes/header.php', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/02dnj_', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)', 'numMentions': 2, 'avgSalience': 0.007887},{'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/03g20', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML', 'numMentions': 28, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}, {'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'PERSON', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 1, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}]
dict1 = [{'name': 'require-once1', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.014624}, {'name': 'require_once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.008366},{'name': 'funkytaurusmedia.com/includes/header.php', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/02dnj_', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)', 'numMentions': 2, 'avgSalience': 0.007887},{'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/03g20', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML', 'numMentions': 28, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":{0:1522254600000, 1:1132254600000 },"url":{0:"http", 1:"http1"},"lang":{0:"de", 1:"de"},"polarity":{0:-0.8, 1:0.8},"magnitude":{0:10.3, 1:11},"score":{0:-0.5, 1:0.5},"entities": {0:dict0, 1:dict1}})
df
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Comment: edited the question, please check it out.

Comment: The input is not an np.array, just a plain list []. If you don't want pandas to read it in as an np.array, change the pandas read code.

Comment: @smci , when I check the type of the entry df['entities'][0], it gives me "numpy.ndarray"

Comment: That's what I said to you: it's not an np.array in the input, it's just a plain list []. It's only an np.array **after** pandas reads it and converts it to an np.array. So change the pandas read code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the column elements, and create a new dataframe from it, then join them together:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['entities'].tolist()))

            date   url  ... numMentions  avgSalience
0  1522254600000  http  ...           4     0.014624
1  1522254600000  http  ...           4     0.008366
2  1522254600000  http  ...           2     0.007887
3  1522254600000  http  ...          28     0.007139
4  1522254600000  http  ...           1     0.007139
[5 rows x 13 columns]
```

For your second example, you could try this:

```
pd.concat(df.apply(lambda row: pd.DataFrame(row['entities'], [row['date']]*len(row['entities'])), axis=1).values)
```

Comment: every row has a variable number of JSON object, so when I convert the column entities to a list, I loose track of which object belongs to which row.

Comment: @Shaheen, ah could you please show what the expected output for your example would be? How do you want to "flatten" the data? 1 row and a list of "numMentions" in that row, or repeat that rows with the date as unique key for the multiple rows which come out?

Comment: I expect every row to have a date, URL, lang, polarity, magnitude, score. Name, type, mid, wikipediaUrl, numMentions, avgSalience repeated 5 times for the first 5 entities in the array of entities associated with that row. 
Also, please note that the sample data provided above only have one row.

Comment: @Shaheen, have you tested the code, it should do exactly that. Because the sample data you provided already has 5 rows. Otherwise please provide a [mre] which recreates the underlaying problem

Comment: my bad, I didn't create a good sample of the data, I edited the question again with the new minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: @Shaheen, updated my answer, if it was helpful please also consider upvoting the answer. Happy coding!